# Null pointer exception while making MongoDB connection on WAS 8.5 web application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, websphere

I am trying to connect MongoDB via web application hosted on IBM WAS 8.5. While making connection to MongoDB which is a sharded cluster i am getting below error -

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=l4dreqdb4967.hewitt.com:30000, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException: java.lang.NullPointerException}, caused by {java.lang.NullPointerException}}, {address=l4dreqdb4968.hewitt.com:30000, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException: java.lang.NullPointerException}, caused by {java.lang.NullPointerException}}]
         at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:377)
         at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:104)
         at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.(ClusterBinding.java:75)
         at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.(ClusterBinding.java:71)
         at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getReadConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:63)
         at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:393)
```

Mongo client being used is - 3.5 
Mongo DB  vesrion - 4 
IT is an SSL connection and we have put the cert file into JDK. 
code used to make connection is -

```
try {
    MongoClientURI connectionString;
    MongoClientOptions.Builder optionsBuilder;
    optionsBuilder = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                        .sslEnabled(true)
                        .sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true);
    connectionString = new MongoClientURI(dbURI, optionsBuilder);
    mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);

    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("SPMQC");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("PersonDocumentData");
    Document mongoDoc = collection.find().first();  
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You are running the code from a servlet?

Comment: Using a database from an application server (IBM WAS 8.5) requires configuration of the database server as _resource_. There is documentation and details about this answered question: [Can MongoDB be used in full WebSphere Application Profile as a data source?](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/173906/can-mongodb-be-used-in-full-websphere-application/).

Comment: Yes you can say so. It is an web application using spring core 3.2 and we have written a *DaoImpl.java where we put this code in static block.

Comment: What line of the code is throwing the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: when we use MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("SPMQC"); on next line it fails